# jQuery script not working inspite of mentioning Lib

Tags: jquery, html

Not to forget, I mentioned this in the head.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My code -

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("img").click(function(){
       jQuery("img").animate({left: '200px'});
   )};
)};
```

HTML -

```
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley" width="32" height="32"/>
```

The code fails to work

Comment: please use jQuery instead of $. What error you get in console...?

Comment: There is no `div`, you have provided only an `img`

Comment: Tried using jQuery instead of $ still no use. I'm not running it in a console.

Comment: @Moltres Can you post the complete HTML?

Comment: Any error in your console... add an alert in the click handle and see whether it is getting called

Comment: What is the `img` in html for.. there is no js code to handle it

Comment: Do you want the click handler to work on the click of the image

Comment: @RinoRaj 
`<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script>  
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
   jQuery("img").click(function(){  
       jQuery("img").animate({left: '200px'});  
   )};  
)};  
</script>  
</head>  
<body>  

<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley" width="32" height="32"/>    

</body>   
</html>`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes. Please see the code again, I made some edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers, I actually got it. All I had to do was Specify it's position.
Working jsfiddle **[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/49702xdn/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() { $("img").click(function() {
$("img").animate({
  left: '200px'
}); }); });
```

HTML -

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/2000px-Smiley.svg.png" style="position: relative; width: 32px; height: 32px;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Braces are placed wrong.

try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery("img").click(function(){
    alert(1);
   jQuery("img").animate({left: '200px'});
   }
  );

  } 
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5t8z0k4b/

Comment: It is not the only issue

Comment: It is not moving to left

Comment: Not moving to left, as @RinoRaj said.

Answer (score 0):

please check below code

HTML

```
<img src="http://design.ubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/ubuntu-logo14.png" alt="Smiley" width="100" height="100"/>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img").click(function(){
   $("img").animate({left: '200px'});
  });
});
```

CSS

```
img { left:50px; position: relative; }
```

Comment: OP is trying to move it to left. Please update your answer

Comment: image is already left so it's not move to left...you need to use css.please check my edited answer

Comment: did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

**Changes made**

Added `css`

```
position: relative;
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").click(function() {
    $("img").animate({
      "left": "300px"
    });
  });
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/Yf3xW/158/)**

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Look at my answer.